Access Statefulsets spesific pod externally on openshift
How to access spesific statefulsets pods by its unique names outside of openshift?
Please provide scalable solution.
I thought about 2 ways but I hope there is better and easier solution.

Path-based routing and ingress.
Wildcard routes and dns mapping.

